# Manually install every thing in GCP VM module

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am new to cloud and still learning GCP, I exhausted almost all my free credit for GCP within 2 months while learning different modules.
GCP is great and provides a lot of things to ease the development and maintenance process.

But I realized using different modules cost me a lot.
So I was wondering if I could have a big VM box, install MySQL, Docker, and Java and React required components by myself, I can achieve pretty much what I want without using extra modules.
Am I right?

Can I use the same VM to host multiple sites by changing ports of API, or do I need to have different boxes for that?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is out of GCP domain but about IT architecture. You can create a big VM with all installed on it. But you have to manage it by yourselves and the scalability is hard.

You can also have 1 VM per website, but the management cost is higher (patching and updgrade)! However you can scale with a better granularity (per website).

The standard pattern today is to explode your monolith server into dedicated services. The database on a specific server, the docker and Java in another one, and the react in a static component (like Google Cloud Platform).

If you want to use VM, you can use GKE and you containerize your application. It's far more easier to maintain your VM with an automatic tool like K8S.

The ultimate step, is to use serverless and/or full managed solution. Cloud SQL for your database, GCS for your static content, and App Engine or Cloud Run for your backend. Like this, you pay as you use and if you website is not very used, you won't be charged on it (except for the database).

Comment: Hi @guillaume blaquiere, yes, ideally your architecture should be applicable, and while learning I did almost the same what you have suggested above, but I realize the more GCP modules I use the more I am burning credits. till free credits it was fine, but now I am looking for sustainable hosting, and yes when my traffic increases I will move on to your architecture.
yes I know scaling and manual backup will be required, but apart from that will my architecture work.